# Set Background Image on GADBannerView

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanna ask how to set `background image` while loading ads until it shows the ads.

```
AdMob = [[GADBannerView alloc]init];
AdMob.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , GAD_SIZE_300x250.width, GAD_SIZE_300x250.height);
AdMob.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
AdMob.adUnitID = [GlobalVariable sharedInstance].PID_IOS_PHONE;
AdMob.rootViewController = self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
[AdMob loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set Image as a background using bellow piece of code:-

```
AdMob.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```